# Get dataframe of duplicates of some columns and VAFs/values within a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 5 columns: gene, lab_id, start, change, and vaf. I want to go through the dataframe and pull out duplicates of gene, lab_id, start, and change and if the duplicates have a VAF that is within a certain percentage (say 25%) of each other, I retain the duplicates. If they are outside of that range, the duplicates are not retained.
For example, I have dataframe

```
| gene | lab_id | start | change | vaf |
|:---- |:------:|:-----:|:-------:|---:|
|A     | 1      | 20    | G>T     | 0.5|
|A     | 2      | 20    | G>T     | 0.49|
|A     | 1      | 20    | G>A     | 0.53|
|B     | 3      | 40    | C>T     | 0.5|
|B     | 3      | 40    | C>T     | 0.4|
|B     | 3      | 40    | C>T     | 0.99|
|A     | 1      | 20    | G>T     | 0.6|
```

and I want the rows

```
| gene | lab_id | start | change | vaf |
|:---- |:------:|:-----:|:-------:|---:|
|A     | 1      | 20    | G>T     | 0.5|
|A     | 1      | 20    | G>T     | 0.6|
|B     | 3      | 40    | C>T     | 0.5|
|B     | 3      | 40    | C>T     | 0.4|
```

I can use the duplicated method to match the four columns, but I am stuck when trying to filter by proximity of the VAFs:
`df_dup = df[df.duplicated(subset = ['gene', 'lab_id', 'start', 'change'], keep = False)]`
I considered itertuples and interrows, but that seems out of place and inefficient. I bet there is something in pandas, but I just haven't come across anything like that.

Comment: How are the first two rows of your output not considered duplicates per your definition?

Comment: @Idr They have different lab_ids

Comment: The first two rows of your output have lab_id 1.

Comment: I'm sorry. The first two rows of the output are duplicates and the 3rd and 4th rows are duplicates. That's what I want, the duplicated rows with VAFs in a certain range of each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def drop_distant(v, margin=0.25):
    return [x for x in v if (sum(abs(x-v)/x < margin)>1)]

columns = ['gene','lab_id','start','change']
is_duplicated = df.duplicated(columns, keep= False)

out = df[is_duplicated].groupby(columns).agg(drop_distant)
out = out.explode('vaf').reset_index()
```

This is the output

```
| |gene |lab_id |start |change |vaf|
|-|-----|-------|------|-------|---|
|0|A    |1      |20    |G>T    |0.5|
|1|A    |1      |20    |G>T    |0.6|
|2|B    |3      |40    |C>T    |0.5|
|3|B    |3      |40    |C>T    |0.4|
```

Comment: I keep getting a ZeroDivisionError, which I think would indicate that there are no duplicates that fit this criteria, but we know that isn't the case....

Comment: Also, I am getting this error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'". I think this idea is good, but there are just some programming humps.

Comment: I think that both cases are related with the vaf column. You should check that only contains non-zero floats, apparently you have some string on it.

Comment: I found the string, and it works... I am curious though... Is there a way to specify aggregation for only the vaf column? If the df has additional columns, this error also seems to pop up.

Comment: If you have more columns you just can reference de column you want to aggregate:

`out = df[is_duplicated].groupby(columns)['vaf'].agg(drop_distant)`

or

`out = df[is_duplicated].groupby(columns).agg({'vaf':drop_distant})`

Comment: That was so obvious, and I did everything except that. LOL. Thanks a bunch for your help.

For anyone else, who wants to use this method, make sure you remove `'vaf'` out of the explode method if you filter for a particular column.